# github にある alpha zero クローンの遊び方がわからない

Tags: rust

https://github.com/coreylowman/synthesis
このリポジトリを見てます。
ざっくり言うとこれはrustで書かれたアルファ碁のようなボードゲームの機械学習プログラムです。
cargo でbuildするのはできました。
また、自己対局による学習もちゃんと動いているようで、
学習したネットワークファイルらしきものも出力されているのが確認できました。
しかしその学習済みのネットワークを使って実際にゲームを遊ぶ方法がわかりません。
READMEを読むと9x7 Connect4 as a playground to test things のような記述があるのですが、具体的な対人ゲームを動かすコマンドは載っていないようです。
このリポジトリに対人ゲームのプログラムは用意されているのでしょうか？